# How to change position of input parent div with radio button?

Tags: html, css

In a container, two radio button inputs are placed. When the static button is checked, the containing div should be `positioned` static, when the absolute button is checked, the container should be positioned `absolute`. How to accomplish this JavaScript-free? Do I need additional markup?

```css
div.container { border: 1px solid black; }

div.container input[id="static"]:checked + label {
    background-color: aqua;
}

div.container input[id="absolute"]:checked + label {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
        <div class="container">
            <input id="static" type="radio" name="position" checked />
            <label for="static">Static</label>

            <input id="absolute" type="radio" name="position" />
            <label for="absolute">Absolute</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: I think to style parent you must use javascript/jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange` to change `container` style

```js
function changePosition(pos){
var cont = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
cont.style.position=pos;
}
```

```css
div.container { border: 1px solid black; }

div.container input[id="static"]:checked + label {
    background-color: aqua;
}

div.container input[id="absolute"]:checked + label {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="static" type="radio" name="position" checked onchange="changePosition('static')" />
   <label for="static">Static</label>

   <input id="absolute" type="radio" name="position" onchange="changePosition('absolute')"/>
   <label for="absolute">Absolute</label>
</div>
```